# Accessing Configuration Inside Symfony Repository

Tags: php, symfony, configuration, repository

I have defined various configuration settings inside my bundle's configuration:

```
src/Acme/MyBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
```

I would like to access various configuration settings defined in services.yml inside a repository class. For example, use a value from the configuration in a where clause.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Don't call us we call you](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollywood_principle)

You can pass the config through the dependency injection container.

```
parameters:
    param1: 'some value'

services:
    my_service:
        class: %my_service.class%
        calls:
                  - [ setParam1, [%param1%]]
```

Comment: This is the method I have been reading about the most. I am still unsure how I would use a service from inside the repository class. I can't use this injection method directly on the repository class because then I will get a "missing 1 argument for __construct()" error. Am I misunderstanding something?